# Update a column in Table with Query (text)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a database which contains query statements in the columns. I need to update this. Is there any way I can update this It seems to be giving me an error:

```
UPDATE Items
SET Query = 'SELECT isnull((sum(OrigDocAmt) ),0) amount from AP where Acct in (1234) and Status='O' and Doc in ('CK') {SLLocCode}'
WHERE ID='111'
```

It gives me an error because it considers 'O' as a separate string. Is there a way that I can do this like in python "What's up". 
Not sure why it was setup this way but it was done so by my predecessor. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 2 single quotes ('') around each literal value

```
'SELECT isnull((sum(OrigDocAmt) ),0) amount from AP where Acct in (1234) and Status=''O'' and Doc in (''CK'') {SLLocCode}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes in the query string.  In SQL Server, you just double the single quotes:

```
UPDATE Items
    SET Query = 'SELECT isnull((sum(OrigDocAmt) ),0) amount from AP where Acct in (1234) and Status=''O'' and Doc in (''CK'') {SLLocCode}'
    WHERE ID = '111';
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to escape `'`(single quotes) in the query. This can be done by simplly doubling it.

```
UPDATE Items
SET Query = 'SELECT isnull((sum(OrigDocAmt) ),0) amount 
from AP where Acct in (1234) and Status=''O'' and Doc in (''CK'') {SLLocCode}''
WHERE ID=''111';
```